# One page is showing the "Index of /" error

Tags: errors

What could be the cause for this? I re-installed WordPress and that didn't fix it, I switched to a default theme, same problem. This is just for one page, all other pages work okay! Please advise :)

Comment: You must have some folder on the root with the same name as this page slug, it's like creating a page with the slug `wp-admin`, so delete that folder or update the page slug.

Answer (score 0):

Doing below works:

- Disable all plugins.
- Using default `.htaccess` if your server used apache for webserver.
- Enable `WP_DEBUG` in your WordPress to see current error.
- Make sure about that page using the Page format?

Otherwise, delete this page and try to create new page.